# Add second and millisecond to the box after selecting the time in ptTimeSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, pttimeselect

Is there any options to add second and millisecond values in [ptTimeSelect](http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html)? Currently I could only select Hour, Minutes, and AM/PM.

```
$('#start-time').ptTimeSelect();
```

Any idea would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just from looking at it for a minute, it doesn't look like it supports anything smaller than a minute.  I guess you could always extend the code to support those extra time increments.  It doesn't look like it would too incredibly hard to do but it's probably easier to just use something else.

Comment: curious what your use case is?

Comment: Ah, i'm doing this by hacking to its library by appending static value 00 after the minute values

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn can you please answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114748/pttimeselect-jquery-timepicker-plugin-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find another way of achieving this beside hacking into it's library. I appended the static value of second (00) before the AmPm taks place. On line 276:

```
 jQuery.ptTimeSelect.setTime = function() {
      var secondsTime = "00";
      var tSel = jQuery('#ptTimeSelectUserSelHr').text()
                 + ":"
                 + jQuery('#ptTimeSelectUserSelMin').text()
                 + ":"
                 + secondsTime
                 + " "
                 + jQuery('#ptTimeSelectUserSelAmPm').text();
          jQuery(".isPtTimeSelectActive").val(tSel);
          this.closeCntr();

  };// END setTime() function
```